# Is it possible to send a computer's screen to an Android device?

Tags: java, android, image, sockets, networking

I was just wondering if it was possible for an Android device to get a computer's screen through LAN at 60 Hz.

I have already made an Android app that connects to a Java program on my PC that takes a screenshot and sends it through a TCP socket to the device where it displays it. However it takes too much time for each image to transfer to view the computer screen in real time.

It is actually possible and that I'm just doing it wrong or is the software or actual device (Mine is HTC Wildfire S) too slow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do some math.  A 1080p screen is 1920×1080 pixels.  In a bitmap, each pixel is 4 bytes (a,r,g,b).  You want 60 of them per second.  That ends up being 497664000 bytes/second, or 497 MB/s.  802.11n is up to 150 megabits/s.  So no, you can't realistically do it without compression.  Now add in compression, and/or reduce your framerate goal and it becomes doable.

Edit:  another technique (one used in video processing as well) would be to send only the parts which changed.  That would be the best way to save bandwidth, and the idea that would probably come closest to your goal.  Most frames are probably 90%+ identical.

Comment: Cheers man. Also thanks for suggesting the idea of compression and sending the changes only.